# Convert / translate Fortran f77 code to C or Matlab / Octave

Tags: matlab, fortran, octave, translate, fortran77

I have an old piece of Fortran f77 code that I would like to understand and edit for future reuse. For that purpose, I would like this code to be translated to either C or Matlab / Octave language. I have found an instance of f2c exe online, but it wouldn't run because of inappropriate OS ( my OS is Win 7 x64, f2c wanted older x32 ).

My main concern is being able to understand the code. Translation in terms of execution efficiency is not of importance. I am open to any suggestion, apart from learning Fortran 77. I am aware of that option myself, but would do it only as a last resort. Thank you.

Comment: You want to understand the code without learning FORTRAN77 ?  I'm not sure that those twin aims are consistent.  Suppose you found something to translate the FORTRAN into a language you do, or are willing to, understand.  How then could you be sure that the translation was correct ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I would trust the translation to a well tested and reliable piece of software, if it exists - finding that is purpose of my question anyhow. And checking whether translation was correct could be done by exposing the translated code to a test case.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark my exact thought. It is like using Google translate to convert something from Spanish to English and blindly accepting that it is correct. While it may be close, an exact match is not guaranteed.

Comment: @JamesC either way, StackOverflow is not the proper place to ask for a suggestion of a tool. All we are likely to do is simply Google it, and maybe find something. You can do the same. I am not trying to be rude, but sometimes you there is not always a nice simply solution. Learn F77, it is the best option and if you know other languages already, it should not be terribly difficult

Comment: As a programmer wanting a C source code, you shouldn't have problem to compile the f2c instead of googling and trying to run old .exe files. http://www.netlib.org/f2c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since are using Octave, you can call Fortran code, there is no need to rewrite it. You will need to write a very simple C++ wrapper to it but Octave already provides macros to do all of the hard work. It is all documented on the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Calling-External-Code-from-Oct_002dFiles.html). Actually, Octave itself calls on many fortran subroutines, so this is perfectly normal.

If you want to modify it, you should be learning Fortran then.

Answer (score 3):

Just learn Fortran. The output of machine-translated code may well be functionally correct and suitable for compilation and execution, but it's going to be really hard to understand and maintain. (Just look at what generated code targeting a single language, like the output of a GUI builder wizard, looks like.) In particular, while Matlab is built on Fortran, its idioms at the M-code level are different enough that it would be pretty incomprehensible. If you already know C or any other Algol-like language, picking up Fortran is not that hard. And the idioms and features that are particular to Fortran – that is, the new stuff you'd have to learn – are probably going to be especially weird and incomprehensible when sent through a translator.

The one translator that might actually be useful is a Fortran 77 -> Fortran 90 translator. The modern '90 dialect would be easier to learn and more succinct, and since the translation is within the same language family the output probably wouldn't be too ugly.

Comment: Note that older F77 codes are often laden with `goto` and obscure the intended design of the loops. Some F77 => F90 translators can determine the intent and modernize it, others cannot.

Comment: +1 Oh jeez, computed goto. That alone could make a translator worthwhile if your codebase is like that.

Comment: Exactly. And at this point, just learning Fortran well enough to translate it is the only *reasonable* option (well, other than learning Fortran *and using it*).